# Boot manager does not find usb stick

Tags: bios, usb-flash-drive, dell-poweredge

I have a dell server Poweredge T110.
I have 2 usb sticks:

## 1: Sandisk Ultra - 32GB - Formatted exFat

## 2: Sandisk Cruzer Blade 8GB - Formatted NTFS

When I go to boot mananger -> Boot settings -> Set legacy harddisk drive order, the T110 only finds stick #1 and not #2.
I have rebooted and switched sticks, a couple of times

Both sticks works fine in windows vista.
What do I need to do to make my Poweredge find the Cruzer?

Thanks /

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you'll need to reformat the Cruzer with exFAT or FAT32 rather than NTFS, which it seems as though the T110's BIOS does not support.

Comment: Hi. This is the tutorial: http://www.altaro.com/hyper-v/installing-and-running-hyper-v-from-a-usb-stick/ 
Ok, so some bios does not support all file systems?
I will follow the tutorial again and see if it is possible to do it with exFat. Thanks

Comment: My guess would be that your BIOS indeed doesn't recognize an NTFS filesystem; I would be interested to hear whether it works with the stick reformatted to exFAT, though.

Comment: I tried a third Sandisk stick and formatted it in exFat, Fat32 and NTFS. All three was found in bios. So, there is something wrong with Sandisk #2, not the Poweredge. I followed the turorial, and chose NTFS on this third stick. Hyper-v is up and running.
Case closed. Thanks for your assistance, Aaron........

Comment: Glad to be of help!